# how to change the AND with OR in a filter Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, telerik

how to change the AND with OR in a filter Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC ?

I unable to replace "AND" with " OR" in the filter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1w82.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your datasource filter logic to "OR"